# Is it possible to Update the rows with data from a table connected with the foreign key?

Tags: sql, database, join, attributes, sql-update

I have a table `[Book]` in a database that has a `[AuthorId]` and `[Description]` columns. The other table `[Author]` is related to the `[Book]` via foreign key `[Book].[AuthorId] -> [Author].[ID]`.

I'd like to update the `[Book].[Description]` column with the text `"Nice book from #Author#"`, where `#Author#` is the name of the author taken from the `[Author].[Name]`.

Something like this:

```
UPDATE [Book] SET [Description] = 'Nice book from ' + [Author].[Name]
```

but the problem is that I don't know if there is a way to join the author and the book from within the `UPDATE` statement, so that each updated row will know it's author's name.

Is this possible in a single SQL query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update Book 
  set Description = 'Nice book from '+Author.Name
from Author
where Book.AuthorID = Author.AuthorID
```

Comment: Oh, my, it's that simple? :) Thanks.

Comment: @Kornelije Petak – Sometimes it is :)

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE [Book] SET [Description] = 'Nice book from ' + [Book].[Name]
FROM [Book], [Author] 
Where [Book].AuthorId = [Author].Id
```